# Evaluating $\int _0^{\pi }\int _0^x\sqrt{1-x^2}\:dydx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate:
$\int _0^{\pi }\int _0^x\sqrt{1-x^2}\:dydx$

I've gotten it done to:

$\int _0^{\pi }x\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$

Should I now change to polar coordinates because of the pi, or how should I proceed?

Comment: If $u=1-x^2$, what is $du$?

Comment: If I use substitution, I am unclear how to deal with the upper limit of pi.

Comment: Treat it like you would with any old integer bound of integration.

Comment: I believe you should recheck your problem. That integral is undefined at $x=\pi$ because you would be taking the square root of a negative number. Once you fix that, you use substitution for the limits as well.

Comment: There must be an error in the statement of the problem. The integrand isn't defined (as a real number, anyway) in the domain described.

Comment: $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is a real number only for $-1\le x\le 1$, so I suppose that the limit $\pi$ is really $1$. in this case use the substitution $x=\sin t$.

Comment: The original question was:  ∫∫D 1−x2−−−−−√dydx  where D is the region in the plane bounded by the x-axis, the line y=x and x=pi

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, my mathjax does not want to cooperate

Comment: I drew the triangle out in the first quadrant, with the line y=x over top of the region of y=0 and hence x=0, to x=pi. From these inequalities I got the outer integral bounds as being 0 to y and the inner bounds as being from x to pi. Is that correct?

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone for the input. Greatly Appreciated!

Comment: @E.JJ Sorry, I thought about the problem and realized that you were right. The outer bounds of integration are indeed from $x=0$ to $x=1$. Sorry for any confusion I may have caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made a typo, the upper limit of the integral looks more like $1$ instead of $\pi$ (otherwise the square root is not well defined), I will give my answer based on this correction.

---

Try to make the change of variable $x = \sin \theta$, the $dx = \cos\theta d\theta$, and the integral becomes
\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 x\sqrt{1 - x^2} dx \\
= & \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin\theta \cos \theta \cos\theta d\theta \\
= & -\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^2(\theta) d(\cos\theta) \\
= & -\left.\frac{1}{3}\cos^3(\theta)\right|_0^{\pi/2} \\
= & \frac{1}{3}. 
\end{align}

Comment: I originally thought there was a typo as well, but the OP just stated in the comments that the original problem was "where D is the region in the plane bounded by the x-axis, the line y=x and x=pi"

Comment: @Simon Anyway then the integrand is not well-defined if $x > 1$.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too. But he just accepted the answer, so I'm assuming he just read the problem wrong.